# Como consumir un servicio que no retorna un json en Angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript

Tengo un problema con el siguiente servicio:
El cual cuando invoca al end point construye una url con 3 parámetros el cual al ser invocado renderiza una vista del servidor.
Al realizar el subscriber de este servicio en el component, en el network  si me arroja la vista pero en consola me arroja "ERROR OK"
No se como es la forma correcta de consumir este servicio
Ya que quiero que esa url se abra en el navegador

```
public clientId = 'newClient';
public redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000';


constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

getOauth() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' });

    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject:{
        client_id: '3',
        response_type: 'code',
        redirect_uri: this.redirectUri
      }
    });
    //return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/oauth2/authorize`, params.toString(), { headers: headers });
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/oauth2/authorize`, { params: params, headers:headers } )
  }
```

}

**MI COMPONENTE QUE CONSUME LO TENGO ASI**

```
 uriOauth2 (){
this.oauthService.getOauth().subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer uso de promesas y manejar la respuesta de una manera más controlada en el componente.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';

export class ConsultationService {

  headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(
    { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' }
  );

  params: HttpParams = new HttpParams({
    fromObject: {
      client_id: '3',
      response_type: 'code'
    }
  });

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getOauth(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiURL}/oauth2/authorize`, { params: this.params, headers: this.headers }).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Ahora bien, si entendí bien quieres redirecciónar a una URL en especifico cuando el servicio responda, puedes usar el router.navigateByUrl() en caso de que sea una ruta del mismo proyecto o usar una función propia de Javascript con window.open(), siguiente esta lógica, sería de la siguiente manera.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ConsultationService } from '@services/consultation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'consultation',
  templateUrl: './consultation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['']
})
export class ConsultationComponent {

 constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private _consultationService: ConsultationService
 )

 uriOauth2(){
   this._consultationService.getOauth().then( (response: any) => {
    //Aquí realizas la lógica que deseas, y controlas mejor la respuesta, ya que aquí se ejecutará después de obtener una respuesta por parte del endpoint.
   console.log(response);
    
  //Si quieres redireccionar a una URL en especifico dentro de la aplicación sería así:
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/url');

  //De la manera de redireccionar con javascript (se puede paginas o URLs externas, sería así:
   window.open('url);
  }).catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
 }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, logre obtener mi codigo